# Can I reuse host buffer memory ad libidum or should I re-map it every frame?

Tags: c++, vulkan

My app has a `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT` buffer and a permanent command buffer that uploads the memory to a `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` buffer.

I have two questions about this setup. This is question 1, question 2 is separate.

---

For better performance, resources (buffers, buffer memories, memory mapping, command buffers, etc.) are allocated outside the main loop. The only thing I do in the main loop (per-frame) is triggering the command buffer with a `vkQueueSubmit()`, which transfers the data from host memory to device-local memory. I took several significant "shortcuts" in respect to literature (the classic Vulkan tutorial everybody starts with). By writing direcly into `stagingMemory` I need no separate memory and no `memcpy()`, and doing most of it outside the loop is even more of a shortcut. This is the pseudo code:

```cpp
void* stagingMemory;
vkMapMemory(logicalDevice, stagingBufferMemory, 0, size, 0, &stagingMemory);

while (running)
{
  // write directly into stagingMemory by fiddling with pointers and offsets

  if (its_time_to_update_ubo_on_device)
  {
    VkQueueSubmit(...) // transfer stagingBufferMemory to device-local buffer
  }
}

// only on exit
vkUnmapMemory(logicalDevice, stagingBufferMemory);
```

This works and I understand this is performant because I minimize instantiations (such as `SubmitInfo` and command buffers) and several other operations. But I wonder if this is safe on the long run. What happens when memory pressure triggers virtual memory pages to be paged out to disk? Can this happen, or is `stagingMemory` safe?

What raises doubts in me, is that I've always read about a very different approach, like this:

```cpp
while (running)
{
  // write to memory (not staging memory!)

  void* stagingMemory;
  vkMapMemory(logicalDevice, stagingBufferMemory, 0, size, 0, &stagingMemory);
  memcpy(stagingMemory, memory, size);
  vkUnmapMemory(logicalDevice, stagingBufferMemory);

  if (its_time_to_update_ubo_on_device)
  {
    SubmitInfo info {}; // re-initialize every time anew
    VkQueueSubmit(... info ...) // upload to device-local memory
  }
}
```

Is this less-optimized approach just for didactic reasons, or does this prevent problems I don't envision, yet, and will ruin everything later on?

Am I doing what is described in [this nVidia blog post](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/how-optimize-data-transfers-cuda-cc/) as *Pinned Host Memory*, or is this something still different?

Comment: Or to put it another way, if there is contention for system memory, you're already in trouble performance-wise, so what does it matter?

Comment: Sincerely, I don't know how many and which applications users may run concurrently. If I'm at the very start of this journey, should I already squander my resources? I don't even know if I'll use depth buffers or add screen space filters to the render pass. But if I'm unrespectful with resources, I'll end up with an ugly result pretty soon :(

Comment: Right now, everything is super-small and embryonic. But I want this project to grow and have solid foundations. I'm not experienced enough to understand how I'm doing in this larval state :)

Comment: I don't understand. If someone is running so many applications that it causes memory pressure... then your program runs slower. Just like all of the other programs. Which is exactly what the user would expect. And they know how to deal with it. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens when memory pressure triggers virtual memory pages to be paged out to disk?

Um... that's not a thing that happens, actually.

Virtual pages are never "paged out"; only *physical storage* gets paged out. The storage underneath a virtual address range can get paged out, but the actual virtual addresses are fine.

Perhaps you're thinking that Vulkan would have to ensure that physical pages associated with a mapped range can't be paged out, lest a DMA operation fail to complete. Well, that's not how Vulkan transfer operations work. They don't require that the memory is mapped *during* the transfer (nor do they require that it is unmapped prior to the transfer. Vulkan doesn't care). So it doesn't matter to Vulkan whether there is some virtual address range bound to the storage; internally, it could be using the actual physical addresses for its DMA operations.

If the GPU needs that range of memory to not be paged out all the time, then it will need it regardless of whether it is mapped. If the GPU is fine with it being paged out, and will page it back in prior to any DMA operations from/to it, then that's a thing that has nothing to do with the memory being mapped.

In short, your question is a non-sequitur: keeping it mapped or not will not affect memory pressure. The only thing it *might* affect is how much virtual memory addresses your program uses. Which in the days of 64-bit programs is really kind of academic. Unless you think you're going to allocate 2^48 bytes of storage.

So the only reason to unmap memory (besides when you're about to delete it) is if you're writing a 32-bit application and you need to be careful with virtual address space *and* you know that the implementation will not assign virtual addresses to CPU-accessible memory unless you map it (implementations are free to always give them virtual address space).